# How to convert maskedtextbox value to int if it's empty?

Tags: c#

I am building this C# windows application. On a certain Form, I am using maskedtextbox to enter upto 3 numerical digits, then I convert it into int as I have to send all these data to database with an insert query, but the problem is that these maskedtextboxes give error when left empty:

```
int scd_user_comm = Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text);
```

and the error is :

> Input string was not in a correct format.

The corresponding field in database allows null, so if left empty, it must not give an error. Can anyone help please?

One side question:: Can I use a textbox or maskedtextbox to ensure that user only enters numeric value b/w 0 to 100? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update the code from one of the answers and then change scd_user_comm to something else. Plain System.Int32 type can't hold a null value (and if your DB supports NULL for that field then NULL and 0 are different).

Comment: There are two ways, using TryParse or checking on String.IsNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the Int32.TryParse() method

```
int scd_user_comm;
if(Int32.TryParse(maskedTextBox1.Text, out scd_user_comm) == false)
     scd_user_comm = 0;
```

this will give you all the flexiblity required to work with your integer var and your maschedTextBox-

To force your maskTextBox to accept only numeric values set

```
   maskTextBox1.Mask = "999";
   maskTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExludePromptAndLiterals;
```

However this is not enough to ensure the enterd number is between 0 and 100. 
To get this result you need to use the Validating event and reject the input if is outside your limits

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int num;
        if (Int32.TryParse(maskedTextBox1.Text, out num) == true) 
        {
            if (num < 0 || num > 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insert number between 0 and 100");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Value of `scd_user_comm` will be `0` after unsuccessful conversion.
That's why you need only `Int32.TryParse(maskedTextBox1.Text, out scd_user_comm)` instead of 2nd and 3rd lines.

Comment: No need to assign **0** to ***scd_user_comm*** variable.

Comment: All right, but this was just an example to explain the workings of TryParse

Comment: hey, thanxx, i figured out a way to use ur code for my purpose, but the validation code for restricting the value b/w 0 to 100 gets quite bothersome when there are a no. of such textboxes on my form, i have to validate it for each one of them,

Comment: i don't think there's any easaier way around

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TryParse instead:

```
int scd_user_comm;
if(!Int32.TryParse(maskedTextBox1.Text, out scd_user_comm))
{
     // Do something to notify the user that the text isn't a number.
}
```

Comment: the actual problem is that if the user leaves the maskedtextbox empty, it gives error, it wont convert it

Comment: The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: @user1479153 - Smileek is right. In the if-clause you can do your database-logic if you wish. TryParse never throws, only returns true/false as a result of trying to convert the value to Int.